# Groovy Bug XmlSlurper?

Tags: groovy

Was developing a code for perser an xml and it did not work because I was using the word Slurper!

example

```
 def slurper = new XmlSlurper ().parseText ("<root><test></test></root>") 
 slurper.root.size () / / Error 

 def parser = new XmlSlurper ().parseText ("<root><test></test></root>") 
 parser.root.size () / / Works FINE! '1 '
```

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Your XML is not the same between the two. Is that a typo?

Comment: Are you sure about that? The tags in first example passed to ParseText look incorrect. They match in the second one. Also you have 'Test' and 'test' as opening and closing tags in second example, isn't xml case sensitive?

Comment: Reformat your question to a runnable format.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, but really did not run, for some reason he did not return the size () correctly. Topic closed. Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing typos and formatting I can confirm your error has nothing to do with the name. Here is an [example of it working](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/2165001).

```
def parser = new XmlSlurper().parseText("<root><test></test></root>")
println parser.size()

def slurper = new XmlSlurper().parseText("<root><test></test></root>")
println slurper.size()
```

Comment: Agree with Joshua - the top example returns size of 1.